# gallery with modal window

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a gallery in PHP. Clicking on each thumbnail should open a modal window with the image and other information.
The problem is that it only works with the first thumbnail and not with the others.
this is part of the php code:

```
        while($i !== $nIMG){
        $recordIMG = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "<div class='content-img'><img src='". $recordIMG['urljpg'] ."' id='infoIMG'></div>";

        $i++;
    }
```

this is the modal window

```
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        </div>
```

this is the javascript code

```
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        var img = document.getElementById("infoIMG");
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
     }
```

I am thinking it is an ID issue which must be unique. But I don't know how to solve, could someone more experienced help me?

Comment: Your hunch is correct: If you replace your while loop with a for loop, and use the iterator in the image id, it will show up correctly

Comment: I replaced the while loop with the for loop, but that doesn't change.

Comment: my javascript knowledge is pretty poor so i don't know how to make an iterator for the id. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, the php part was okay. Add `onclick="openImage(this)"` to it, and than move to the javascript part.

There, you would need a new function to pass the image src. I also re-named the modal image class to a more general one: `image-content`

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("image-content");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}


// Look at this code: element is passed to the function
function openImage(element) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  // This is where the magic happens :)
  modalImg.src = element.src;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <h2>Modal Example</h2>

  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <div class='content-img'><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=1" onclick="openImage(this)"></div>
  <div class='content-img'><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=2" onclick="openImage(this)"></div>
  <div class='content-img'><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?random=3" onclick="openImage(this)"></div>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content" id="myModal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="image-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

before getting your answer i tried to create two for loops in php and javascript and it works. These are the codes:

PHP:

```
        $n = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i !== $nIMG; $i++){
        $n++;
        $recordIMG = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "<div class='content-img'><img src='". $recordIMG['urljpg'] ."' id='infoIMG".$n."'></div>";
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    var nr = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){

    nr++;

    var y = "infoIMG" + nr;

    var img = document.getElementById(y);
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    }
    
    }
```

Everything seems to work fine. Do you think it might be okay or is it better to use the code reported by you?
If I use this code, the only doubt is to understand how to pass the number of rows of the mysql database as the second parameter of the JS for loop.

Comment: For the number problem: you can still have a hidden input field with the exact number of the images passed into the HTML, but its' quite hacky. But I'm glad you experienced some with it! :) It's a better practise, to have a dynamically managed system, than to hard code values